# flask python,javascript variable issue?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

my flask code section that have issue
**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
import pandas as pd 
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    df = df.groupby('name')['marks'].sum()
    j = df.to_json(orient='index')
    return render_template("work.html",s=j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and i want to pass j into my javascript file that is look like that
**work.js**

```
//pie chart
var s = {{ j|safe }};
var keys = [];
   for(var k in s) keys.push(k);
var value = [];
   for (var k in s) value.push(s[k]);

var data = [{
  values: value,
  labels: keys,
  type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
  height: 400,
  width: 500
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv1', data);
```

**work.html**

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="navbar"><span>data representation with Plotly.js</span></div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="myDiv1"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src={{ url_for('static', filename='work.js')}}> 
            </script>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

how to pass j variable in flask to s variable in javascript file that render with html page and show right content or say that no graph shown
Thank you

Comment: Can you add stack trace of the error? Also, are you sure that you don't have any caching issue?

Comment: there's not much to go on here, but it appears that your `s` in the JS script is in fact a (JSON) string. Try `s = JSON.parse(s)` before the loops.

Comment: oh, and you refer to wanting to "pass j into my javascript file" - only the `work.html` template get the `{{s|tojson}}` converted to the actual value. This will work if this is in a script tag in the template though (which is what I assumed when I first read your post).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You have to return that json in your flask method and make an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from javascript.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/')
def home():
    j = df.to_json(orient='index')
    return jsonify(j)
```

I don't know if flask has something like `JsonResponse` as django has. If yes you should use that like: `return JsonResponse(j)`

```
$.ajax({url: "your_url", success: function(result){
    //result is what you returned from flask
}});
```